# Nature of the solution of BVP.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, eigenfunctions

For the boundary value problem,   $\,\,y''+\lambda y=0; y(0)=0,y(1)=0, \,\,\exists$ an eigenvalue $\lambda$ for which there  corresponds an eigenfunction in $(0,1)$ that

1. does not change sign
2. changes sign
3. is positive
4. is negative

We have result says that eigen function corresponding to least eigen value does not change it sign and corresponding to $\lambda _k$ where $k>1$, eigen function change it sign hence option 1 and 2 are correct. Now here $y_1(x)= \sin(\pi x)$ which is positive and we know that if  $y_1(x)$ is a solution then  $-y_1(x)$ is also a solution. Then 3 and 4 are correct. Is the thought correct?

Comment: please check someone.

Comment: Why don't you solve the DE for the cases $\lambda < 0, \lambda = 0, \lambda > 0$ and see what you get?